# query template in py2neo?

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

Does py2neo support any manner of query templating? My current need is to support simple date ranges. I could do it by inserting a WHERE clause into the query text. Before I do that, maybe there's a better way?

For example, assume certain node types have a date. I would like to be able to specify a WHERE clause that would filter the selection. But I don't always want to filter it. Think query params from an HTTP request.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit what kind of templating you expect? You can use Cypher queries with parameters (http://py2neo.org/2.0/intro.html#transactions).

Comment: I think there is no template in that sense, a function with an optional `date=None` parameter would be the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Py2neo does have an extension for handling Dates.
This may help you - http://py2neo.org/2.0/ext/calendar.html